# Using value from textinput in python

Tags: python, kivy, textinput

I want to make an app which would print text entered in TextInput when I press Print.
After a couple of hours of searching the web I still can't understand how to assing value of TextInput to variable in python script.

This is Kivy code:

```
<SimpleRoot>:
    orientation:"vertical"
    padding: root.width * .02, root.height * .02
    spacing: "10dp"
    TextInput:
        id: txt
    Button:
        text: 'Print'
        on_press: root.printTxt(txt.text)
```

Python script:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class SimpleRoot(BoxLayout): # 2
    def printTxt(text):
        print txt.text


    pass

class SimpleApp(App):  # 1  
    def build(self):
        # Return root widget 
        return SimpleRoot()

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    SimpleApp().run()
```

Comment: What happens when you run now? Do you get some sort of error?

Comment: Yes. When I write something in TextInput and click 'print' I get: File "D:/Documents/Python\simple.kv", line 9, in <module>
     on_press: root.printTxt(txt.text)
 TypeError: printTxt() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
class SimpleRoot(BoxLayout): # 2
    def printTxt(text):
        print txt.text
```

To this

```
class SimpleRoot(BoxLayout): # 2
    def printTxt(self, text):
        print text
```

Comment: I did, but now it returns this error: File "D:/Documents/Python\simple.kv", line 9, in <module>
     on_press: root.printTxt(txt.text)
   File "D:/Documents/Python/textinput.py", line 8, in printTxt
     print txt.text
 NameError: global name 'txt' is not defined

Comment: Look at my new edit and see if that works. I got rid of the txt.text and replaced with just text